# getting rid of timestamp in returned string

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, timestamp

I want to get rid of the timestamp in this returned string. I am currently getting: 
"You have selected:
Fri Sep 08 1978 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (EDT)"

The code is:

```
var chosenDates = $.datepicker.parseDate('yy-mm-dd', dateText);
$('.info').html('You have selected:' + '<br />' + chosenDates.toString());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the format in the `toString` method. For example:

```
var chosenDates = $.datepicker.parseDate('yy-mm-dd', dateText); 
$('.info').html('You have selected:' + '<br />' + chosenDates.toString('dd-MM-yyyy'));
```

**Edit:** Or if you want to use the same format as in the date-picker: `yy-mm-dd`

**Edit:** You can also try with the `formatDate` function:

```
var chosenDates = $.datepicker.parseDate('yy-mm-dd', dateText); 
var backToString = $.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', chosenDates);
$('.info').html('You have selected:' + '<br />' + backToString);
```

Comment: I've tried that parameter and a bunch of others, but it's not working.

Comment: can you elaborate? do you get the exact same output regardless of what you specify for toString? Or is there another problem?

Comment: yes, the same output every time, no matter what parameter I put in, including my own dateFormat like in your edit.